# Are there any side effects of setting downLevelIteration to true in TypeSript / Angular projects?

Tags: angular, typescript

For the data which TypeScript thinks is not iterable, it suggests us to set downLevelIteration to true, which results in finer level of iterative code internally.

Want to understand if this would cause any side effect in the application.